# DbContext trying to create tables

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

I have  a custom DbContext class.
I have existing tables in the system.
I have setup a POCO based system.

When I try to query the DbSet for  a table, then it tries to create the table.
Now the table already exist in the DB, sql server will throw exception.

How to suppress creation of tables via EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your DbContext implementation:

```
// static constructor
static MyDbContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When application is starting (e.g. `Application_Start()` method of `global.asax.cs`) instruct the strategy you want to use for db creation:

```
 Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContext>());
```

`Database` is in `System.Data.Entity` namespace.

In case of using `new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContext>()` it'll drop the database and try to create that if there is a change between db schema and POCOs.

Comment: I don't want to drop the db and recreate again. I just don't want EF to try to create the database and the tables.